# In which case Null Pointer Exception throws in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Suppose I have a code on line no 33 as

`c=a.b();`

It throws `nullpointer exception`, whether it throws for:

1. For method `b()`
2. For `c`
3. For `a`

Regards.

Comment: All of them. Debug it. Set a break point on the code and inspect your variables.

Comment: Why don't you try it ?

Comment: Please post the relavent code

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on the code for method `b()`

Answer (score 4):

That statement will throw a `NullPointerException` *if and only if* `a` is `null`.

(It is possible that an NPE exception could be thrown *within* the call to the `b` method ... but the stack trace would show clearly that the NPE is being thrown in a different statement to this one.)

Comment: What about any invokation on any `null` reference inside `b()`? Just wanted to understand

Comment: @Octopus Then there it happens. Not in this statement ;) That is what Stepehn mean.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ ha ha ha, perfect! I am always being silly,. Stephen got +1

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - yup.  that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It probably throw for your `a` variable because you want to get its class function which is not defined.

Comment: You are guessing ... aren't you :-)

Comment: Sorry, you're faster than me :)